# Oracle Where with variable

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have problem with my plsql code. It's just part of my whole job.

```
declare 
id number(2):=1; (here is function which returns any value)
check VARCHAR2(100);
begin
select COUNT(*) into check from T_SDSN_LOG Where ANY_ID=id AND CHECK LIKE 
'NAME';
dbms_output.put_line(check);
end;
```

In this case, my select returns 0 althought it should be 2.
If I change the part 
Where ANY_ID=id to 
Where ANY_ID=2 
it works perfectly. Any advices? I need id to be variable as a return value from function.

Comment: Perhaps table `t_sdsn_log` contains column `id` which takes precedence over the variable `id`?

Comment: [Documentation link to expand Ponder's comment](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/plsql-name-resolution.html#GUID-A551A39D-7DF8-4525-BE0F-1F46FE04ED09). It looks like `check` is also both a column and local variable name, though in this case you do want seem to want the column (but using `like` with a non-wildcard value is odd). It is better and safer to prefix local variables, or table/unit name qualifiers.

Answer (score 0):

This uses a locally defined function so it isn't available in the SQL but can be referenced in the PL/SQL.

```
DECLARE
   lnum_id      NUMBER := return_id;
   lnum_check   VARCHAR2(100);

   FUNCTION return_id
      RETURN NUMBER
   IS
   BEGIN
      RETURN 123456;
   END;
BEGIN
   lnum_id   := return_id;

   SELECT COUNT(*)
   INTO   lnum_check
   FROM   my_table
   WHERE  table_id = lnum_id;

   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(lnum_check);
END;
```

You will presumably want this functionality in a package in which case you can declare the function in the package header, write the code for the function in the body and then reference it in the SQL itself. So if I declare a function (FNC_RETURN_ID) in a package called PKG_DATA_CHECKS that returns a NUMBER I can do the following;

```
DECLARE
   lnum_id      NUMBER;
   lnum_check   VARCHAR2(100);

BEGIN

   SELECT COUNT(*)
   INTO   lnum_check
   FROM   my_table
   WHERE  table_id = (SELECT pkg_data_checks.fnc_return_id FROM dual);

   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(lnum_check);
END;
```